# Firebase Push Notification Not receive in background but recieves on foreground

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Push notification does not work on background IOS production. App written on flutter. It works when I try in development mode, but not on production. When I publish app on Testflight, only foreground messages shows. Message recieves only on foreground not on background. When I send message from server, it appears only on foreground, even background message appears only on foreground. I tried to change APN certificates, but result is the same.
My sending message is like bellow.

```
{
 "to" : "/topics/782",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "body is here",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification",
     "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
     "channel_id": "example.de",
      "sound":"true"
 },
  "apns": {
        "headers": {
            "apns-priority": "5"
        }
      }
}
```

My AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseAuth

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
         UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
       }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

           let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
             options: authOptions,
             completionHandler: { _, _ in }
           )
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

         Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
           #if DEVELOPMENT
                //Develop
                Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .sandbox)
            #else
                //Production
                Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken as Data, type: .prod)
            #endif
         super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
       }
}
```

On debug mode notification shows on foreground and background. Even message from Firebase message reacts like that. Please help me to figure it out, where is my problem.

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#ios), especially adding `Background fetch` with Xcode?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I followed this guide, my problem was on AppDelegate.swift file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed AppDelegate to below code, in my case it works perfectly.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
    if(!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Notification")) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Notification")
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

// This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
   override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
        {
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
}
```